# Java - создание абстрактного класса

Tags: java, классы, uml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На руках имеется такая UML. Не понятно как сделать абстрактный класс  AbstractProcess и чем служат методы  stepBefore(), stepAfter(), больше нет никакой информации.

Comment: Из остального что-нибудь понятно/реализовано? Если есть код, то вопросы лучше задавать по нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже это должно выглядеть так:

**Orderable.java**

```
public interface Orderable {
    boolean checkout();
    boolean pay();
}
```

**AbstractProcess.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractProcess {
    public void process(Orderable item) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented");
    }

    public void stepBefore() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented");
    }

    public void stepAfter() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented");
    }

    public abstract void action(Orderable item);
}
```

**CheckoutProcess.java**

```
public class CheckoutProcess extends AbstractProcess {
    @Override
    public void action(Orderable item) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented");
    }
}
```

**PaymentProcess.java**

```
public class PaymentProcess extends AbstractProcess {
    @Override
    public void action(Orderable item) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented");
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
public class Order implements Orderable {
    private int id;
    private String status;

    public String getStatus() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method not implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkout() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean pay() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Это только скелет, построенный по диаграмме. Все методы должны быть реализованы явным образом в зависимости от Ваших целей.
Надеюсь это поможет двигаться дальше.